# Bash syntax error near unexpected token `done' vi editor highlighted in red

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to learn how to use while loops in Bash scripts and I have the following script.

```
#!/bin/bash

continueKey = "y"
while [continueKey -ne "n"]
DO

        echo "Menu Options"
        echo "1 - whoami"
        echo "2 - df"
        echo "3 - date"
        echo "4 - cal"
        echo -n "Select option: "

        read option

        case  "$option" in

                1) whoami
                ;;

                2) df
                ;;

                3) date
                ;;

                4) cal
                ;;
               *)
                echo -e "\e[31mYou made an invalid selection. Exiting.\e[39m"
                exit 1
                ;;
        esac
        echo "Enter another command?"
        echo -n "Press 'n' to exit. Any key to continue "
        read continueKey
done
exit 0
```

When I execute it I get:

```
syntax error near unexpected token `done'
```

In the vi editor the done command is highlighted in red. What do I have wrong here?
Thanks,

Comment: first part of script didn't copy

#!/bin/bash

continueKey = "y"
while [continueKey -ne "n"]
DO

Comment: First part of script didn't copy

Comment: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a couple of issues right at the beginning of your script:

```
while [continueKey -ne "n"]
DO
```

`continueKey` needs `$` in front of it, otherwise it's just an invalid command. `DO` should be lowercase, since it's case sensitive. `-ne` should be `!=` since you are not comparing integers.

```
continueKey="y"
while [[ $continueKey != "n" ]]
do
```

I haven't looked at the rest of your script, although that's issue in regards to your question.

Comment: Yes that was it, Thank You.

Comment: Also, you need spaces between the elements of a test command or conditional expression. That is, `[ $continueKey != "n" ]` will work, `[$continueKey != "n"]` will not. The same applies to the double-bracket version. (The answer has this right, I thought it'd be worth pointing out explicitly.)